# Angular ng-model is not working in multiples views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-view

I'm trying to build a single page application with ng-view but at this time I've a problem about ng-model. I've followed this tutorial [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) and all is working perfectly except ng-model. 
I've added a form with a single input text with ng-model and a button who calls a function in my controller. When button is submitted, I load a view where I try to get my ng-model but whithout success...

See below my code :

**home.html**

```
    <div>
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" ng-model="actia.name"  placeholder="Saisir un mot"><br>
                <button ng-click="toSend()">OK</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute']);

MyApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
            .when('/',{
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            }).when('/contact',{
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            });
//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

MyApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.message = "Message du main Control";
    $scope.actia = {
        name : '',
        lastname : 'goerge'
    };
    $scope.toSend = function(){
        var donnees = $scope.actia;
//        $location.url('/contact');
        console.log(donnees);
    };
});
```

**contact.home**

```
    <div>
        <h2>Contact Page</h2>
            <p>Value is : {{actia.name}} {{actia.lastname}}</p>
    </div>
```

{{actia.lastname}} is displayed but not {{actia.name}}
Have you any suggestions to solve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That is because you get a new Controller for each route. They don't know each other. 
YOu may need a factory/service to keep the data in sync between those two views.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm a begginer in Angular, could you show me how to use a service in this case please ? Thanks a lot

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers it shows how to use a factory to share data between controllers.